# Flash Actionscript 3.0 scene not found, but scene exists

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Actionscript question:

'#2108: Scene Madwoman was not found.' is my error.

My code is:

```
Crazy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextScene);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(1, 'Madwoman');
}
```

[image: This is a screenshot from FLASH CC scenes panel to show that the scene exists]

Comment: It appears when you choose "Test Scene". Try "Test Movie" to reach all the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself, code should have been:

```
Crazy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextScene_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextScene_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Solved it by doing this:

```
btMyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent) {
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(1, "MySceneName");
});
```

Hope it helps someone.